# Powershell 'Get-Date' constant stop working

Tags: powershell

I was using below code in one of my power-shell script and for some reason I have formatted my machine, Now I found that this isn't working in power-shell.

```
$dt = Get-Date 06-15-21
$dt
```

Now its throwing below error

```
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "06-15-21" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:16
+ $dt = Get-Date 06-15-21
+                ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Comment: It depends on the language setting of your machine. It should always work like this: `Get-Date -Month 6 -Day 15 -Year 2021`

Comment: You can try doing this which ***should*** work `$dt = [datetime]'06-15-21'`

Comment: Error seems obvious - there's only 12 months in a year, not 15 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While PowerShell is mostly culture-*invariant*, this doesn't apply to the parameters of *binary* cmdlets<sup>[1]</sup>, unfortunately. That is, **how a date string such as `'06-15-21'` is converted to a [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instance by [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) depends on the *current culture*** (as reflected in `$PSCulture` and `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`) and is therefore not guaranteed to work the same on all machines.

By contrast, **PowerShell's *casts* (`[<type>]`) *are* culture-*invariant*** (they use the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), so [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s solution is correct:

```
# Culture-invariant cast that works on all machines.
# The invariant culture is based on the US culture, and recognizes
# "MM-dd-yy" strings (month first).
[datetime] '06-15-21'
```

If you still need `Get-Date`, you can simply pass the result of the cast as the argument; e.g.:

```sh
Get-Date ([datetime] '06-15-21') -UFormat %s
```

Alternatively, as [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) points out, you can bypass the culture-dependent string parsing by specifying your date unambiguously by its numerical components:

```sh
Get-Date -Month 6 -Day 15 -Year 2021
```

Note the need to specify the year in full (`-Year 21` would result in the year 21 CE, not 2021).

---

To illustrate **the original problem**:

```
$origCulture = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture

# Try the Get-Date command first with the US English culture, 
# then with the French culture in effect.
'en-US', 'fr-FR' | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "In culture ${_}:"
  [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = $_
  Get-Date 06-15-21
}

[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = $origCulture
```

You'll see that with the US-English culture in effect (`'en-US'`), the date string *is* recognized, whereas with the French culture (`'fr-FR'`) it is *not*, because in that culture the *day* of the month is expected to come first.

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, parameters of PowerShell functions and scripts *are* culture-invariant. This inconsistency is a known problem, which, however, will *not* get fixed, in the interest of backward-compatibility - see [GitHub issue #3348](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3348#issuecomment-337799446).</sup>

Comment: Even in `en-US`, the statement `Get-Date 06-15-21` fails, emitting `Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "06-15-21" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String '06-15-21' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."` This is on pwsh 7.1.3.

Comment: No, @lit - run the last snippet and you'll see with `en-US` in effect  `Get-Date 06-15-21` outputs `Tuesday, June 15, 2021 12:00:00 AM`. If it doesn't for you, a different culture must be in effect.

Comment: `Get-Date 06-15-21` works fine for me on `en-US PS5.1`.

Comment: `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` produces LCID=1033, Name=en-US DisplayName=English (United States). `Get-Date 06-15-21` produces `Get-Date: Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "06-15-21" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String '06-15-21' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

Comment: @lit, I just tried on Windows 7 as well, and it works as expected there too. The only explanation for the nonstandard behavior you're experiencing that I can think of is that you've customized the locale definition via Control Panel / `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`

Comment: @mklement0, yes, I have changed the regional settings for short date and time to present in ISO-8601 standard formats. Oddly, `Get-Date -Date '06-15-21'` FAILS, `Get-Date -Date [datetime]'06-15-21'` FAILS, but `Get-Date -Date ([datetime]'06-15-21')` WORKS,

Comment: @lit: That is to be expected: `[datetime]'06-15-21'` is an _expression_ and in order to use that as a command _argument_, it must be enclosed in `(...)` (as also shown in the answer). Try `Write-Output [datetime]'06-15-21'` vs. `Write-Output ([datetime]'06-15-21')`

Comment: @mklement0, I think I understand about the parentheses enclosure. But I wonder why '06-15-21' works when cast as [datetime], but not when there is no cast. The -Date parameter is a [System.DateTime]. Does it not do an implicit cast?

Comment: @lit: As explained in the answer, PowerShell's casts alway use the _invariant_ culture.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to utilize ISO 8601 format, so that there are no issues with respect to system locale settings.

```
$dt = (Get-Date "2021-06-15")
$dt
```

> Tuesday, June 15, 2021 12:00:00 AM

With Date and Time

```
$dt = (Get-Date "2021-06-15T23:59:59")
$dt
```

> Tuesday, June 15, 2021 11:59:59 PM